# BIDS Package runs in BIDS but not at command line

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bids

I made a dtsx package that moves data from one database to another. When I run it in BIDS it runs fine. When I run it from the command line as me it runs fine. When I run it at the command line as the service account I created for it, I get an error that the source DB's local sql server user\password is incorrect. Obviously that can't be true, since the username and password for the source DB's local user is embedded in the project.

I tried giving domain/service account DB admin permissions, as well as full server admin permissions. That didn't do anything. I also tried giving the local account LD_Transfer001 more permissions, but that also didn't do anything. The only way I've been able to get this to work is by running it as my domain admin account at the command line. I have also verified the folder where the packages live has the correct permissions.

**Running as Domain/service:**

SQL Log:

```
Login failed for user 'LD_Transfer001'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Command line error message:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.4000.0 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.

Started:  9:47:57 AM
Error: 2014-10-15 09:47:57.74
   Code: 0xC0016016
   Source:
   Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0
x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized
 to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic err
or. Verify that the correct key is available.
End Error
Error: 2014-10-15 09:47:57.76
   Code: 0xC0016016
   Source:
   Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0
x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized
 to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic err
or. Verify that the correct key is available.
End Error
Progress: 2014-10-15 09:47:57.88
   Source: Data Flow Task
   Validating: 0% complete
End Progress
Error: 2014-10-15 09:47:57.92
   Code: 0xC0202009
   Source: FranchiseeInfo Connection manager "LDHQSQL.001"
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred.
 Error code: 0x80040E4D.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0
"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'LD_Transfer001'.".
End Error
Error: 2014-10-15 09:47:57.92
   Code: 0xC020801C
   Source: Data Flow Task OLE DB Source [1]
   Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAG
ER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "LDHQSQL.001" f
ailed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before thi
s with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
End Error
Error: 2014-10-15 09:47:57.92
   Code: 0xC0047017
   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: component "OLE DB Source" (1) failed validation and returned err
or code 0xC020801C.
End Error
Progress: 2014-10-15 09:47:57.93
   Source: Data Flow Task
   Validating: 50% complete
End Progress
Error: 2014-10-15 09:47:57.93
   Code: 0xC004700C
   Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline
   Description: One or more component failed validation.
End Error
Error: 2014-10-15 09:47:57.93
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: Data Flow Task
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  9:47:57 AM
Finished: 9:47:57 AM
Elapsed:  0.266 seconds
```

**Running as me[open command prompt normally**
No command line error message

```
Login succeeded for user 'LD_Transfer001'. Connection made using SQL Server authentication. [CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

Comment: You're using a config file, aren't you?

Comment: I don't think so. All I have is the dtsx package.

Comment: What's the value of "ProtectionLevel" in the package properties?

Comment: EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey

Comment: Change to **DontSaveSensitive** and retry!

Comment: After switching, I get the same error at teh command line. In addition, it fails in BIDS.
[OLE DB Source [1]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "LDHQSQL.001" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Comment: Sorry, gave you the wrong option (d'oh!). See my more complete answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sensitive information (i.e. the password) are encrypted in the package. The encryption key generated is from the user account of the machine the package was developed.

Therefore when running via service, the decryption key is not available and the password cannot be read and used.

There are a couple of options available to resolve:

1. Use Windows Authentication in your connections in the package.
2. Use a configuration file to set the ConnectionString. Check the connection string in the config file has a plaintext password.
3. Set the *ProtectionLevel* property of the package to either *EncryptSensitiveWithPassword* or *EncryptAllWithPassword* and provide the password to DTSExec.

Method 1 is the simplest, but not always appropriate.

Method 2 is a nice workaround, but leaves the password in plaintext. I tend to opt for this method as the location for our DTS packages is secure and we occasionally have to reconfigure stuff. I like config files!

Method 3 is a sound solution too. Have a read here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138023.aspx.
You need to pass the password using the `/decrypt` option of `dtsexec`